# git clone in openshift fails "no user exists with uid"

Tags: git, ssh, openshift, gitlab-ci

I would like to test and build a Python module which has further dependencies in a gitlab runner (docker) on an openshift cluster. I get my Python module checked out from git as expected.

The dependencies of the python module are named in the setup.py file.

```
[part of my setup.py]
install_requires=[
    "test @ git+ssh://git@ssh.xxxxx.de/path/to/test.git@1.1.0#egg=test",
    "test1 @ git+ssh://git@ssh.xxxx.de/path/to/test1.git@1.0.0#egg=test1",
],
```

When I try to check out the dependencies when installing the module, I get the error message that no user with the uid x exists.

```
Collecting test@ git+ssh://git@ssh.xxxx.de/path/to/test.git@1.1.2#egg=test
Cloning ssh://****@ssh.xxxx.de/path/to/test.git (to revision 1.1.0) to /tmp/pip-install-423fkywm/test
Running command git clone -q 'ssh://****@ssh.xxxx.de/path/to/test.git' /tmp/pip-install-423fkywm/test
No user exists for uid 1056080000
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

This problem is known and is related to the openshift cluster and the fact that the pod is started with a random id, which is identical per namespace. [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openshift/4-iLzir043s)

Do you know possible solutions to work around this problem?